# Why would I get Kernel Panic after wiping my MacBookPro10,1 SSD and starting from scratch? Looking for help to resolve this kernel panic

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, kernel-panic

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report: 2102 sec Panics Since Last Report: 1 Anonymous UUID: A2D9708D-90D9-6291-C995-53578F118FF4

Sat Apr 10 22:45:46 2021 panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff80232b8945): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa46091d4, type 14=page fault, registers: CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000010, CR3: 0x000000000a3c3030, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0 RAX: 0x0000000000000001, RBX: 0xffffff81c4ae6000, RCX: 0xffffff80484e12a8, RDX: 0xffffff81eb7b3a38 RSP: 0xffffff81eb7b3b60, RBP: 0xffffff81eb7b3b60, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x0000000000000000 R8: 0x0000000000000000, R9: 0x00000000000003ff, R10: 0xffffffffffffffff, R11: 0x00000000ffffffff R12: 0xffffff81c4ae6000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000002, R15: 0x0000000000000000 RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff7fa46091d4, CS: 0x0000000000000008, SS: 0x0000000000000010 Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000010, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x4

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff81eb7b3800 : 0xffffff802321d636 0xffffff81eb7b3870 : 0xffffff80232b8945 0xffffff81eb7b3a40 : 0xffffff80232cebfd 0xffffff81eb7b3a60 : 0xffffff7fa46091d4 0xffffff81eb7b3b60 : 0xffffff7fa45f28c4 0xffffff81eb7b3bb0 : 0xffffff7fa45f281a 0xffffff81eb7b3bd0 : 0xffffff7fa45ce2ee 0xffffff81eb7b3c00 : 0xffffff7fa3e85380 0xffffff81eb7b3c40 : 0xffffff7fa3e852ef 0xffffff81eb7b3c60 : 0xffffff7fa3e8a746 0xffffff81eb7b3cf0 : 0xffffff7fa3e82e30 0xffffff81eb7b3d20 : 0xffffff7fa3ffb963 0xffffff81eb7b3d70 : 0xffffff802363c61b 0xffffff81eb7b3dc0 : 0xffffff802366dbb7 0xffffff81eb7b3e30 : 0xffffff802329876f 0xffffff81eb7b3e80 : 0xffffff8023220b4d 0xffffff81eb7b3eb0 : 0xffffff8023210448 0xffffff81eb7b3f00 : 0xffffff802321961b 0xffffff81eb7b3f70 : 0xffffff80232a6546 0xffffff81eb7b3fb0 : 0xffffff80232cf473 Kernel Extensions in backtrace: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7fa3e79000->0xffffff7fa3eaffff dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[6C1D646D-7E5E-3D7F-A557-2CBA398FF878]@0xffffff7fa378a000 com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.6)[EA4F9902-5AAE-3F1D-A846-3796221C8C91]@0xffffff7fa3ff8000->0xffffff7fa4299fff dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[6C1D646D-7E5E-3D7F-A557-2CBA398FF878]@0xffffff7fa378a000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7fa3f4c000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7fa3e79000 com.apple.GeForce(8.1.6)[7C67749B-3B6B-38A9-8203-01A139C21895]@0xffffff7fa45ca000->0xffffff7fa4697fff dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.6)[EA4F9902-5AAE-3F1D-A846-3796221C8C91]@0xffffff7fa3ff8000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[F16E015E-1ABE-3C40-AC71-BC54F4BE442E]@0xffffff7fa3f4c000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[6C1D646D-7E5E-3D7F-A557-2CBA398FF878]@0xffffff7fa378a000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[9928306E-3508-3DBC-80A4-D8F1D87650D7]@0xffffff7fa3e79000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer Boot args: -no_compat_check -v

Mac OS version: 12F45

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID: EA38B02E-2B88-309F-BA68-1DE29F605DD8 Kernel slide: 0x0000000023000000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8023200000 System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 21962565092 last loaded kext at 21646209601: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60 (addr 0xffffff7fa49f2000, size 28672) loaded kexts: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60 com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.0d1 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.1.7f4 com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.13.12 com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.0.7d2 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim 1.0.0 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 2.4.7fc4 com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124 com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.5.12 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics 8.1.6 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 4.1.7f4 com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.4.7fc4 com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.4.7fc4 com.apple.GeForce 8.1.6 com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5 com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.5 com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.1.7f4 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.11d1 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0 com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup 8.1.6 com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.4.5 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.1.6 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 2.0.3d0 com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.1.11 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.6.3 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 237.1 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver 237.1 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1 com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1 com.apple.BootCache 34 com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.3.5 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 635.4.0 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 3.6.2b4 com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC 1.4.3 com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 615.20.17 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 621.4.6 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI 635.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 2.6.6 com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 1.5 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 1.9 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 214.0.0 com.apple.security.quarantine 2.1 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 4.0.39 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 214.0.0 com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 86.0.4 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 10.0.6 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.1.7f4 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 74.15 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.5.6 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.4.7fc4 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.9.2fc7 com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 1.12 com.apple.nvidia.gk100hal 8.1.6 com.apple.NVDAResman 8.1.6 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.1.7f4 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.4.7fc4 com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.4.7fc4 com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.4.5 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.3.7 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.5d4 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.11d1 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.3.7 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.4.1d13 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink 1.2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 2.5.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 623.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 2.5.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 2.5.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter 1.3.2 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.3.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 621.4.6 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite 621.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 1.9.2 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.7.7 com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 530.5 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 630.4.4 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 635.4.0 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.5.1 com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 7 com.apple.security.sandbox 220.3 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 28.21 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 1.8 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8 com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4 com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0 Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM 421.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 512 MB Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020 AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17) Bluetooth: Version 4.1.7f4 12974, 3 service, 21 devices, 0 incoming serial ports Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet, Ethernet, en1 Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0 PCI Card: Apple 57762-A0, sppci_ethernet, Thunderbolt@10,0,0 Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM512E, 500.28 GB USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087 (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2 USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8510, 0x1a110000 / 3 USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087 (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2 USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424 (SMSC), 0x2512, 0x1d180000 / 3 USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0262, 0x1d182000 / 5 USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 4 USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8286, 0x1d181300 / 8
```

Comment: MacBook Pro 2012 - that's right in the target zone for a failed NVidia GPU. There was a repair program for the faulty ones, but it closed long ago. idk if this may be any use… https://dhavaldalal.wordpress.com/2018/05/29/how-to-disable-failed-discrete-gpu-nvidia-geforce-gt-650m-for-macbook-pro-101-mid-2012-on-high-sierra-10-13-4/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you [edit the post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to format the log file as a code block, it will be formatted more nicely and avoid the “this guy is pasting logs and there is no real question here” automated checks.

Comment: The formatting is still off, all the line breaks seem to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

A kernel panic after an erase and install is the ideal situation for troubleshooting. It removes all the third party apps and configuration changes and user data as a cause.

You are left with three big areas now to blame:

1. The install process was bad or you have a bad build. (OS is not healthy or correct)
2. Your accessories are triggering this condition but the system and OS are healthy and correct.
3. Your hardware is deficient and the OS is healthy and correct.

Are you looking for more about what a kernel panic is or more about what you can do next?

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a solution to resolve the kernel panic

Comment: Start on the 1-2-3 steps above. It’s some work but being organized and keeping notes as you work through the causes may save a trip to a repair shop @Matthew - but it could just mean you need a repair.